# Why is npm not honoring user/global npmignore?

Tags: windows, npm

My editor produces workspace files and backup folders which are of no interest to users of the software I write.  In order to avoid having to list my editor-specific ignores in each project, I'm trying to tell npm to ignore them at the user or global level.

Unfortunately, I'm having no luck doing so.  Running `npm pack` inside my project folder, even if I clear the npm cache first, includes both the workspace file and and **two megabytes** of backup files.  (For a project with only *ten kilobytes* of code!)  I've tried the `ignore` config setting, a per-user `.npmignore`, and a global `npmignore`, all to no effect.

Here's my output from `npm config ls -l`, snipped to relevant sections:

```
; userconfig C:\Users\benblank\.npmrc
ignore = "__history *.epp"

; builtin config undefined
prefix = "C:\\Users\\benblank\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm"

; default values
globalignorefile = "C:\\Users\\benblank\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\etc\\npmignore"
userignorefile = "C:\\Users\\benblank\\.npmignore"
```

And the (identical) contents of `C:\Users\benblank\.npmignore` and `C:\Users\benblank\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmignore`:

```
__history
*.epp
```

What am I doing wrong?  I'm running Windows 7, node@0.8.9, and npm@1.1.61.

Comment: [`globalignorefile` is "documented but unimplemented"](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/npm-/m2eQPMRrjIc), still it seems (v2.5). `/etc/npmignore` not working either.

Comment: [known bug](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2634)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are major [outstanding issues](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues?q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen%20.npmignore) related to `npmignore` files.

Thankfully there is an even better alternative! It is the package.json [`files`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json#files) property.

Here is an example from my [delivr](https://github.com/sholladay/delivr/blob/d6feeb7a9d9e86d19b317077929989e41feb874f/package.json#L27) project.

```
"files": [
  "lib",
  "index.js"
]
```

Why is it better?

1. The internal machinery makes this mechanism more reliable.
2. It is a whitelist instead of a blacklist. Typically, assuming you use a `lib` folder (or similar), there are less files/directories you want *included* vs those you want *excluded*, so it is more succinct.
3. It is [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). If a `.npmignore` file exists, `npm` will not consult `.gitignore` for ignore patterns, which often needs overlapping and repetitive info. This problem does not exist with a whitelist.
4. One less file in the repo. `package.json` is already a manifest that defines your package and it makes a ton of sense for this configuration to live there.